# Is there any basic rules of indenting any code

Tags: coding-style, indentation

This may seem a very trivial question but I would really like to have an answer:

I always seem to indent my code in the following fashion:

```
if (<condition>)
{
     <some code>
}
```

That is, I place my braces in a fashion that makes the code appear within a block. However, as I come across other programmers and even professional code on major websites and my workplace, I observe this:

```
if (<condition>) {
     <some code>
}
```

Is there any significant difference in the two styles of indentation or is it just a matter of choice? This is my personal opinion that the latter format seems a little messier. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Second one is ever so negligibly comnpact .

Comment: Personal preference... The latter is known as K&R-style after Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, the creators of UNIX

Comment: I can recommend you to read Christian Hujer's old blog post http://www.riedquat.de/prog/style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two schemes you enumerate are Stroustrup (the creator of C++) and K&R (from the C book)

Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Which one is better is down to personal opinion (in my opinion); and that's outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: apparently the first one i used was the Allman Style. The Stroustrup version is slightly different as the opening braces still begins on the same line of code instead of a new line. (courtesy wiki). Thanks for the link though it cleared everything :)

Answer (score 1):

The two separate styles will/should execute the same, however if you take a look at PEP8 (Pythons code style guide) you will find that there are *rules/guidelines* to follow which will allow your code to look nicer and easier to read. This is what a lot of python programmers will follow.

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Installing flake8 and running it through your code will highlight any errors within the code against the PEP8 Style guide

[Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8)

Comment: I agree. Python is however a special language in itself because it treats indentation so differently than others and each tab is treated with a special meaning. Blocks in Python are created using indented code after all...